# Can I use "at the latest" in questions?

Tags: questions, antonyms, future-time

Can I use *at the latest* in a question while asking for *nearest possible deadline* as in the following:

> When can you complete it at the latest?

(I want to mean:  *What is the nearest day in future before which there is no possibility to complete it?)*

If not, then how should I reword it?

Comment: No.  The nearest possible deadline would be "at the earliest", which is the opposite of "at the latest".  "At the latest" would be the farthest possible deadline, or just *the deadline*.

Comment: In English, we don't put spaces before tall punctuation.

Comment: Semantics is part of language.

Comment: @MAKZ: Well, I don't know what your native language is, but I'm prepared to bet it has words equivalent to *early/earliest* and *late/latest*. And if you're talking about the *first* possible date/time in the future, that would obviously be the *earliest* date (nearest to "now", where the *latest* date would be the *last* possible date, furthest away from now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as commented by Victor Bazarov, you use the phrase "at the earliest" for the nearest possible deadline as opposed to "at the latest"
for the farthest possible deadline.

Second, you use the time or the date in front of these phrases.

Third, you can use these phrases in the interrogative.  For examples:

Can you complete it by Sunday at the latest?

Can you complete it by tomorrow at the earliest?